# Increase width of bars and give space between two bars BarChart using AChartEngine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I added two `XYSeriesRenderer` to `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.` I need to customize `XYSeriesRenderer` want to increase width of bars i include this code but it didn't works `rendererm.setLineWidth(10);`

Then both bar are attaching closely so need to give some space between both `XYSeriesRenderer`? This code `mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5);` is working for `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`, but i need to give space between two `XYSeriousRenderer`. Please refer my code and picture try to give your suggestions.

```
seriesm = new CategorySeries("Male");
for(int i=0; i < malec.length; i++){
seriesm.add("Bar"+(i+1),malec[i]);
}

seriesf = new CategorySeries("Female");
for(int i=0; i < fmalec.length; i++){
seriesf.add("Bar"+(i+1),fmalec[i]);
}

dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();  
dataSet.addSeries(seriesm.toXYSeries());                           
dataSet.addSeries(seriesf.toXYSeries());   

//customization of the chart

rendererm = new XYSeriesRenderer();     
rendererm.setColor(Color.RED);
rendererm.setDisplayChartValues(true);
rendererm.setLineWidth(20);

rendererf = new XYSeriesRenderer();     
rendererf.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
rendererf.setDisplayChartValues(true);
rendererf.setLineWidth(30);

mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();  
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererm);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererf);

mRenderer.setChartTitle("Gender");
mRenderer.setYTitle("No of Reports");
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);    
mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);      

mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5);   
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0); 
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(2);
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);   

layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.barchart);
mChartView=ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getApplicationContext(), dataSet, mRenderer, org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);
layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
renderer.setBarWidth(width);
```

for setting width of bar.

Comment: thanks for your time its working fine. How to make little space between two bars ?

Comment: You can use setBarSpacing look here for more http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setBarSpacing(double)

Comment: I already use that code but it wont work here. That code works for multiple values in single `categoryserious` but here am using multiple `categoryserious`